# Store API keys for our API

Tags: security, amazon-api-gateway

I'm building an HTTP API with API gateway and want to use API keys for authentication. Since they aren't supported by HTTP APIs, I plan on verifying them manually in a Lambda function.

Where would the best way to store these keys be? I'd rather not spin up a db just for this. I thought about just using parameter store because they will (for the moment) only be used internally and we need to store just a few. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe even something that can generate and rotate these keys automatically?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/kms/ or https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Comment: thanks, I thought both where more for storing 3rd party keys